# Android Studio stuck at downloading components

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just opened my android studio and it showed me "Downloading components" dialog with message "Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 24.2".

[image]

Now I never called for this update and it did not ask for it to me either. I am waiting for about half an hour for this damn thing to complete, but its simply stuck.

Is there any way to simply eliminate this auto update and download of android SDK tools in android studio?

Comment: worst case scenario, you could download the latest version with the SDK bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Close your Internet connection and start the studio. It worked for me!.